# How to dynamically specify the content of a Material Design tab?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to bind the content and label of an `<md-tab>` from the data source. In the component source, I have an array describing the tabs that I would like to show:

```typescript
  tabs = [
    {
      label: 'Tab 1',
      content: `<strong>Tab 1</strong> template`
    },
    {
      label: 'Tab 2',
      content: `<strong>Tab 2</strong> template`
    },
  ];
```

I am able to bind the label using either:

```html
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [label]="tab.label">
    <!-- ... -->
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

.. or:

```html
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
    <template md-tab-label>{{tab.label}}</template>
    <!-- ... -->
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

But how do I include the content within the tab?

Comment: What happens if you put this: `<p [innerHtml]="tab.content"></p>` inside the `md-tab`?

Comment: @developer033 When I try that, basic markup appears okay, but it's not like a template. For example, when I add `<button md-raised-button>Raised button</button>` to the content string, a Material Design button component is not rendered. Also, there isn't a `<button>` element.

Comment: Have you find the answer, Please share if you implemented it. thankyou in advance